# how many ways are there to place 7 iPhones and 5 galaxies in a row such that no galaxies are next to each other?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I realize that there are 7 iphones, so when I place them with a spot between each one of them, then there are 8 spots in total. Can I do $$\binom{8}{5}7!? $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$7!$ ways to arrange the iPhones.

$\binom85$ ways to choose spots for the Galaxies.

$5!$ ways to arrange the Galaxies.

So in total, there are $7!\times\binom85\times5!$ ways.

Answer (score 1):

$$\binom{8}{5}.7!.5! $$ 
the phones themselves can switch places